# What's the point to have public method in class but not in interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface

For example:

```
public interface IMessageService
{
   void ProcessMessages(IEnumerable<Message> messages);
}
```

Implemented the interface:

```
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
     public void ProcessMessages(IEnumerable<Message> messages)
     {
        // whatever
     }
}
```

Then realized that ProcessMessages should be broken down a little bit to handle different parts of the message:

```
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
     public void ProcessMessages(IEnumerable<Message> messages)
     {
       foreach (var msg in messages)
       {
          ProcessCustomer(msg.Customer);
       }
     }

     private bool ProcessCustomer(Customer c)
     {

     }
}
```

Next, wanted to unit test `ProcessCustomer` so made `ProcessCustomer` `public` and at this point the method is not accessible without a cast, so what's the point?.

Comment: Don't make `ProcessCustomer` public just for the sake of unit testing!

Comment: Review the title. It does not appear to be what the code shows or what the problem is about.

Comment: Aside from the other answers here, consider making a `CustomerProcessor` object (or interface!). The `MessageService` can be provided an instance of the `CustomerProcessor` when constructed (or however) and use it to perform processing. You can then write unit tests to test a single processing (in the context of a `CustomerProcessor`) and write tests for your `MessageService` whereby you pass mock CustomerProcessors and validate that each customer was "processed" (even though technically nothing happened). This is very general though; not sure if this is a good fit for your _actual_ code.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - I haven't gotten that far yet, but ya, that's a good point and a possible design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider following. You go to the pizza shop and you want to test their pepperoni pizza. Do you want to test how sausage slicer works? No. You want to see five pieces of pepperoni sausage on your pizza - that is *requirements* for pizza shop. Actually it even does not matter whether sausage was cut manually or with slicer. You should only verify that all *requirements* are implemented correctly.

Same with your class - it's requirement is processing messages. It does not matter how processing of messages is implemented - whether it calls some helper method inside, or not. So, my advise is always same - do not test private methods - they are not required to exist, and their existence should not be tested.

Comment: So, it seems like you are saying that there should not be a public member in the class that didn't originally come from the interface definition?

Comment: @O.O exactly. Your class do some work for other class(es). And neither of them need to process customer. So, if there is no clients for this method, then there is no reason to make it public. Have you ever seen public sausage slicer in pizza shop? :)

Comment: Hah. Ya, this was the kind of answer I was looking for and it makes sense.

Comment: Yes agreed with @SergeyBerezovskiy. It looks like the ProcessCustomer is something not directly related to the MessageService class, it will violate Single responsibility principle from a OOP standpoint. 
If it is indeed related, it should be made public instead and unit testing is all making sense now.

Comment: @HOKBONG - You bring up another good point, which I will think about as well.

Comment: I *half* agree with you, I think your analogy is a bit too vague. While your analogy is 100% valid for functional tests, it's not completely valid for unit tests. My library may expose a handful of public classes, and have dozens of internal classes that make it all work. The end-user doesn't care about those, but I certainly have to unit test them. The costumer may not care, but the line manager certainly does ;)

Comment: Let me put it in another way: internal classes *should* be unit tested, but internal methods *most likely* don't. I think granularity is the key here. In @O.O 's particular case, I agree with you, it doesn't need to be unit tested.

Comment: *I meant to say broad, not vague.

Answer (score 3):

You should make the ProcessCustomer method internal and then add an `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute in your AssemblyInfo.cs file so that your unit test assembly can access the method (but not any other assemblies). Further, you should make the MessageService class internal as well so no outside assemblies can access it. This way, only public part of your design is the interface.

Alternatively, instead of mocking around with the internal access modifier, I've at times used an approach similar to this:

http://exposedobject.codeplex.com/

Comment: And let's not ignore that your unit test can still call into even a private method by using reflection - so that is not really an excuse anyway.

Comment: +1, that is indeed the most common approach. However, one should still consider whether you *should* be testing an internal method. Unit tests are supposed to test a type's interface, not its innards. That being said, oftentimes you *do* need to do this.

Comment: To add to the point from @dcastro, in this instance it is quite likely that you might find that for performance reasons you want to do some batched operation (e.g. via LINQ) and get rid of the foreach. At that point your test is broken, whereas if you'd kept to testing the public interface your tests would still be valid.

Comment: If I was only concerned with unit testing this may be the answer I was looking for, but I will say that messing around with AssemblyInfo and/or using a third party thing to test a method is not very appetizing.  Testing the method's side effects seems to be appropriate and will not impact my design.

Comment: @O.O this is not "messing around", and you don't need any third party tools. This is actually a documented way to unit test internal stuff. From MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `ProcessCustomer` method is not part of the interface so you would need to cast to the object type before being able to use it.

If you are accessing this object type through the interface you would need to cast to the `MessageService` type object first.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question why method in interface is not public:

Interface by design is a contract and implicitly made public. This is by design in the language. So there is no need to use the keyword public.

Comment: Please re-read the question, sorry if it is confusing, but I think you missed something.